# How to find the length of non unique characters in list

Tags: tcl

How to find the length of the list and its value of non-duplicate / unique values in TCL

For Eg : ABABC
===>Expected is  result is
No.of unique character is 1 and its value C

Comment: You might consider changing your question title which asks for *non unique* characters, while your question body talks about getting the length of *unique* characters

Answer (score 1):

```
set str ABABC
foreach char [split $str ""] {incr count($char)}
foreach key [array names count] {
    if {$count($key) == 1} {
        incr nuniq
        lappend uniq $key
    }
}
puts "$nuniq: [join $uniq ,]"
```

```
1: C
```

In place of `split`, you can get the characters of a string with `regexp -all -inline {.} $str`

For old Tcl, you can do:

```
proc myincr {varname {step 1}} {
    upvar 1 $varname var
    if {![info exists var]} {
        set var $step
    } else {
        incr var $step
    }
}
```

and use `myincr` in place of `incr`

Comment: I tried the option.But getting error msgset str ABABC
foreach char [split $str ""] {incr count($char)}
foreach key [array names count] {
    if {$count($key) == 1} {
        incr nuniq
        lappend uniq $key
    }
}
puts "$nuniq: [join $uniq ,]"    .Getting the below error ==>can't read "count(A)": no such variable
    (reading value of variable to increment)
    invoked from within
"incr count($char)"
    ("foreach" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"foreach char [split $str ""] {incr count($char)}"
    (file "t.tcl" line 2)

Comment: @Amirtha You are using a Tcl version before 8.5? You should consider upgrading, since you won't get support for versions before that... As a workaround, you can add `if {![info exist count($char)]} {set count($char) 0}` on one line before the [`incr`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1476) and add `set nuniq 0` before the second loop like [here](http://codepad.org/uC4Ee8Y8)

Answer (score 0):

Another Way To Do It,

```
set var "ABCABDF"
foreach v [split $var ""] {
    lappend a $v
}

puts $a

set unique [lsort -unique $a]

set unique_chars ""

foreach item $unique {
    set cnt 0
    foreach i $a {
        if {$item == $i} {
            incr cnt
        }
    }
    if {$cnt == 1} {
        set unique_chars [lappend unique_chars $item]
    }
}

;# To Print Unique Chars
puts $unique_chars
```